# How to find record count of every single day for a given period in a single sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table `routes` with their effective and expiry dates.

```
r_no name eff_date exp_date
1 test1 01-jun-2013 INF
2 test2 10-jun-2013 15-jun-2013
3 test3 01-jan-2013 25-jun-2013
4 test4 01-feb-2013 31-dec-2013
```

Input will be given by the user say for Eg: 01-Jun-2013 to 30-Jun-2013`

I need to get the count of the routes for each and every day in that entire period.

```
Date Routes_Count
01-Jun-2013 3
02-Jun-2013 3
.
.
10-Jun-2013 4
.
.
20-Jun-2013 3
.
.
30-Jun-2013 2
```

Could someone help me to get the above results using a single query in Oracle 11g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way,

```
WITH cte AS
     (SELECT     TO_DATE ('01-jun-2013', 'dd-mon-yyyy') + LEVEL - 1 dte
        FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                      TO_DATE ('30-jun-2013', 'dd-mon-yyyy') + 1
                    - TO_DATE ('01-jun-2013', 'dd-mon-yyyy'))
SELECT   cte.dte, COUNT (1)
    FROM cte, routes
   WHERE cte.dte BETWEEN NVL (routes.eff_date, '01-jan-0001')
                 AND NVL (routes.exp_date, '31-dec-4000')
GROUP BY cte.dte
ORDER BY 1;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9252c/3)

Here `cte` is the temporary table that I have generated, which gives all the dates from 1st June to 30th June. Join this with your `routes` table, so that the date is within the effective and expiry date of the route. Note that, if there is no exp_date or eff_date, i substitute it with a date which is too far in the future or too far in the past. Now that you have got all the routes for each date, group by the date, to get the count.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wrongly clicked the unaccepted button. This is working absolutely fine.